# iOS. Is it legal to store app bundle in Documents folder?

Tags: ios, dynamic, localization, app-store

I want to dynamically update localization of my iOS application without submitting an app update on App Store.

I know that i can't modify main bundle of my app (that stores Localizable.strings) without submitting an update to App Store because it's read only.

But there is one thing i can try: my application can download another bundle (with updated Localizable.strings files) from some FTP server to Documents folder and get new localization from there.

**So my question is**:

Is it legal to download new app bundles from FTP servers and store them in Documents folder without submitting an App Store update?

By "Is it legal" i mean: wouldn't my application get rejected by iOS App Store?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your app will be rejected, because Apple will not be aware of what you are actually downloading. But this really sounds like a **super overkill** and a **super bad** solution. You could store your strings in a file or database on your server and load it when your app launch, and have some code to handle it in app.

Comment: Follow-up query: should StackOverflow add a triple-highlighting super-underline text mode? **super bad** is completely the right response, it's just a shame that the nature of a web page means that none of us can circle it and draw in huge big arrows pointing towards it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended and absolutely not supported. Please consider shipping localizations as part of an app update.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the exact same thing as every other developer in the world does and stop trying to be smarter than the system: push app updates when you update your app.

If you want to download your own special app using your own special app update mechanism to /Documents then expect at least:

1. users to post reviews thinking you're malware;
2. the application not to download half the time because the user hasn't given  your app access permissions; and
3. the downloaded application not to launch because the user hasn't gone out of their way to give it Gatekeeper permissions.

Also make sure you've done a cost/benefit analysis on Apple somehow not spotting the Gatekeeper prompt when testing your application and somehow not spotting it later.

Comment: I just want to have a way to fix some localization errors. My app will have orver 60 localizations. Push an app update every time when some misprint was found - is a bad choise. Of course my application will have localization in it's main bundle, so it isn't critical to not to download updates.